# Slicing Pandas DataFrame according to groups properties

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame, let's say with two columns, `Group` and `R` (which is negative here). For instance:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group':np.random.randint(0, 5, 20), 
                   'R'    :np.random.rand(20) * -10.0})
```

I would like to create a new DataFrame with, in each group (so for lines having the same `Group`) only the smallest `R` and the lines lower than, say, the smallest `R`+3.

For example, if `df` looks like (I sort it by `Group` and then by `R` for clarity)

```
Group    R  
1       -10.1
1       -12.3
1       -15.5
2       -8.7
2       -9.0
2       -11.4
2       -11.5
2       -13.1
2       -15.9
```

The function should return

```
Group    R  
1       -10.1
1       -12.3
2       -8.7
2       -9.0
2       -11.4
2       -11.5
```

How do you do that?

Comment: Did you mean the smallest or largest plus 3?

Comment: The smallest (negative) plus 3. If the smallest is -10, then I want to select `R`between -10 and -7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first group by 'Group' and return a boolean whether each value in the group is less than 3 more than R. Then use this to filter the original dataframe

```
keep = df.groupby('Group')['R'].apply(lambda x: x < x.min() + 3)
keep
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
....

df[keep].sort_values(['Group', 'R'], ascending=[True, False])

   Group     R
0      1 -10.1
1      1 -12.3
3      2  -8.7
4      2  -9.0
5      2 -11.4
6      2 -11.5
```

Comment: Perfect. I understand now why I was puzzled: I had a misconception about how groupby.apply works. It's much clearer now, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

By using `groupby`

```
df['Max']=df.groupby('Group')['R'].transform('max')
df[(df['Max']-df['R'])<3].drop('Max',1)

Out[105]: 
   Group     R
0      1 -10.1
1      1 -12.3
3      2  -8.7
4      2  -9.0
5      2 -11.4
6      2 -11.5
```

One line solution:

```
df[(df.groupby('Group')['R'].transform('max')-df['R'])<3]
```

Comment: Thanks bud. Your solution is also very interesting, it teaches me things! :)

Answer (score 1):

First sorting and then select by boolen mask:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Group', 'R'], ascending=[True, False])
df = df[df.groupby('Group')['R'].apply(lambda x: x > x.iat[0] - 3)]
print (df)
   Group     R
0      1 -10.1
1      1 -12.3
3      2  -8.7
4      2  -9.0
5      2 -11.4
6      2 -11.5
```

Similar solution:

```
df = df.groupby('Group')['R'].apply(lambda x: x[x > x.iat[0] - 3]).reset_index(level=0)
print (df)

   Group     R
0      1 -10.1
1      1 -12.3
3      2  -8.7
4      2  -9.0
5      2 -11.4
6      2 -11.5
```

Comment: Nice, cheers mate! Didn't know iat, but it seems that it's similar to iloc.

Comment: yes, it is iloc for scalars - iloc can return multiple rows, iat return only scalar.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. :) Unfortunately, it does not work for me... It keeps values it shouldn't (and I loose `Group`, which I need).

Comment: Interesting, for me it works. Your real solution is a bit different?

Comment: I've just tested it with the random mock sample given. Maybe should I mention that I'm using Python 2.7... Could it be why?

Comment: no, it is no difference. Do you use first solution?

Comment: by maybe problem is I filter max value per group - 3 like your data.

Comment: No, I was using second solution. I think I could fix that. But other solutions like Ted Petrou's one works, so I will be using it. I would like to be able to use your solution properly though, because I have a lot of rather issues to solve and your way seems very general.

Comment: Yes, it is up to you what solution use. In my opinion the fastest should be a bit improved `Wen` solution like `df[(df.groupby('Group')['R'].transform('max')-df['R'])<3]`